# TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener

Tags: android

Ho do I Hour and the Minute Value in the Fragment, in which I launche this Timepicker:

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

I tried it with this Code here in the Fragment:

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view,
            int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Log.i("",""+hourOfDay+":"+minute);
        textview.setText(""+hourOfDay+":"+minute);
    }
};
```

but it did set anything

Could you help me getting the Values from the Timepicker?

**EDIT**
This is the Fragment...

```
public class EditStoreFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private ViewPager awesomePager;
private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 9;
AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;



TextView textview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentview, container, false);



    awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
    awesomePager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);


    //...


    return view;

}

class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public View v2;
    DialogFragment timepicker;


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
    }

    /**
     * Create the page for the given position. The adapter is responsible
     * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
     * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
     * {@link #finishUpdate()}.
     * 
     * @param container
     *            The containing View in which the page will be shown.
     * @param position
     *            The page position to be instantiated.
     * @return Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not
     *         need to be a View, but can be some other container of the
     *         page.
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        v2 = new View(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        timepicker = new TimePickerFragment();

        collection.getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

                    //...

            break;
        case 1:

                    //...
            break;

        case 2:
            v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_open, (ViewGroup) null,
                    false);

            ((TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.titel_wt)).setText("MONTAG");

            textview = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.textview);



            textview
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            timepicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

                            Log.i("","opentimepicker");



                        }
                    });

            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view,
                            int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        Log.i("",""+hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                        textview.setText(""+hourOfDay+":"+minute);

                        textview.invalidate();
                    }
                };


            break;

        case 3:
            //Like in case 2 but with other textview...

            break;

        case 4:
            //Like in case 2 but with other textview...

            break;

        case 5:
            //Like in case 2 but with other textview...

            break;

        case 6:
            //Like in case 2 but with other textview...

            break;

        case 7:
            //Like in case 2 but with other textview...

            break;

        case 8:
            //Like in case 2 but with other textview...

            break;
        }

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v2, 0);
        return v2;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a page for the given position. The adapter is responsible for
     * removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
     * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate()}.
     * 
     * @param container
     *            The containing View from which the page will be removed.
     * @param position
     *            The page position to be removed.
     * @param object
     *            The same object that was returned by
     *            {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed. At
     * this point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been
     * added or removed from the container as appropriate.
     * 
     * @param container
     *            The containing View which is displaying this adapter's
     *            page views.
     */
    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
    }

}
```

}

thx

Comment: Try calling textView.invalidate() after textview.setText(), so that your textview will get re-drawn.

Comment: You want the TimePicker value into a textView, right? If so check my answer.

Comment: @ab11 I tried it, but did not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will get the `TimePicker` value you setted and will display in a TextView.

```
tvHora = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHora);

    final Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = d.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = d.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //set current time into textview
    tvHora.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":").append(pad(minute)));
```

Where `tvHora` is my TextView.

Comment: And where do I get the Text from the TimePicker?

Comment: look in the code, it says `//set current time into textview` then code below is it.

Comment: you know that the textview is not in the TimePicker?

Comment: Yes i do. Look, `tvHora` which is the textview, `.setText(...)` inside the set text is the value that you have setted in the TimePicker.

Comment: Ah ok, but as far as I can see you get the time from the Calendar and not from the TimePickerDialog

Comment: You get the time from the value you setted in the TimePickerDialog

Comment: In this [DOWNLOAD LINK](http://www.4shared.com/rar/HGQAChhx/timepicker.html?) you can download a example of how i explained it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand from your code where you are using your `mTimeSetListener`. This should work:

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(...);

        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view,
            int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Log.i("",""+hourOfDay+":"+minute);
        mTextView.setText(""+hourOfDay+":"+minute);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just edited my Post for clearification... I want to set the Text in the Fragment and not in the TimepickerDialog

Comment: Okay. Can you show your Fragment layout and where the TextView is? At the moment, you are just returning a TimePickerDialog in the onCreateDialog of your TimePickerFragment. So there won't be any TextView. Are the Fragment and the TimePickerDialog supposed to be separate?

Comment: What do you mean with separate? Timepicker has to be called on several textviews, so I can't just set the text in the timepicker itself
(I just added the Fragmentcode)

Comment: Now I understand. When you were talking about a Fragment, I assumed you meant the TimePickerFragment. I'll take a look.